# Add square brackets around reference numbers

Tags: bibtex, brackets

I am using TexStudio with .bib file for writing references. I am using bibliography style as iet. I get the references as shown below:

[image]

However, I wish to add square brackets around the references numbers. For example, I want my reference to appear like:

[1] Liu, S., Wang, X., Liu, P.X.: ‘Impact of communication delays on secondary
     frequency control in
         an islanded microgrid’, IEEE Transactions on Industrial
Electronics, 2015, 62, (4), pp. 2021–2031

Please tell me, how can I add square bracket around the reference as shown above

Comment: Please post `MWE`...

Comment: We have used latex Template for IET Generation transmission and distribution. MWE would require all the class files for that journal also

Comment: How would anyone be able to help you without an MWE?

Comment: are you redefining \@biblabel somewhere?

Comment: @ebcontrol No. Can we redefine biblabel to get those square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{\hfill[#1]}
\makeatother
```